# Invalid redeclaration on CoreData classes

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nsmanagedobject

I am working with CoreData, on an entity called "RoleName".

The problem is: I click on "Create NSManagedObject subclass" from within my model, and so it automatically creates the classes for my entity.

However, on the declaration of the class, I get this error:

> Invalid redeclaration of "RoleName"

even though I don't have any other class with the same name.

Comment: did you find any solution yet? And are you using Xcode8 and ios 10 ?

Comment: Deepukjayan's answer should work with you. its working with me.

Answer (score 179):

This is because Xcode handles all that by itself. I felt it like a bit of trouble as the auto generated classes don't have all my properties.

So follow these steps to get this as it used to be:

- Delete what ever classes you already made for core data.
- Set class.Module as Current Product module
  [image]
- Set Class.codegen as Manual/None

[image]

- Now select your entity and create NSmanagedobject subclass
  [image]
- You are all set

Comment: The "Current Product Module" step is very necessary. Thanks @Deepukjayan

Comment: Awesome! worked without this step `Delete what ever classes you already made for core data.`

Answer (score 18):

From Apple : [Whats new in Core Data](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/releasenotes/General/WhatNewCoreData2016/ReleaseNotes.html)

> **Xcode automatic subclass generation**
>
> Xcode now supports automatic generation of NSManagedObject subclasses in the modeling tool. In the entity inspector:
>
> Manual/None is the default, and previous behavior; in this case you should implement your own subclass or use NSManagedObject.
>   Category/Extension generates a class extension in a file named like ClassName+CoreDataGeneratedProperties. You need to
>   declare/implement the main class (if in Obj-C, via a header the
>   extension can import named ClassName.h).
>   Class Definition generates subclass files named like ClassName+CoreDataClass as well as the files generated for
>   Category/Extension.
>
> The generated files are placed in DerivedData and rebuilt on the first build after the model is saved. They are also indexed by Xcode,
>   so command-clicking on references and fast-opening by filename works.

You don't need to manually create subclasses for `NSManagedObjects`.

I would suggest that you delete the files that you created with `NSManagedObjects` (Move them to Trash) and go to every entity in the DataModel Inspector under `Codegen` select : `Manual / None` and create than the Subclasses.

Comment: I am sorry my question wasn't clear about this. Anyway, I generated the subclasses automatically

Comment: So if I understand this correctly, When configured with Module "Global namespace" (the default) & Class Definition, or Category/Extension. Xcode automagically creates a class definition for the entity, which it stores in derived data and is not presented to the user as a "normal" .swift file in the project. By running "Create NSManagedObject Subclass..." Without specifying a different module, we end up creating a second class definition in the global namespace, hence the "Invalid redeclaration" error. Do I have that correct?