# Data with SwiftUI and CoreData

Tags: core-data, swiftui

I'm trying to display data in SwiftUI from a .xcdatamodeld file
If I make the class I've got an error ["Invalid redeclaration of ..."](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6SuVG.png)
And if I delete the class and I use only the extension I've got the error ["Use of undeclared type ...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/75ssM.png)
(Links lead to images)

What can I do ?
Thank you

Comment: Check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40410169/invalid-redeclaration-on-coredata-classes

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `ListeVetements` is an entity defined in your model and you have left the code generation option in your model for this entity to `Class`:

Your second approach (define a static func in an extension) should actually work.

But as you have played around with creating the classes yourself, try clean `cmd+shift+k`.

These code generation errors sometimes be very sticky. closing Xcode and deleting derived data sometimes helps `rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData`

Comment: I already tried to clean the project...  But @CranialDev solution is working thanks !